# Fabric integration in android project which contains unity .aar project

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crashlytics, aar, google-fabric

I have developed android app and fabric implemented for trace crashlytics, its working fine.In that project added unity game as a .AAR dependency file. Game also working fine. Game start's from android app and navigate back to android app also. Now am added fabric for unity game and execute game as a individual project it working fine ,crashlytics also working.Issue is i want to track unity game issues from AAR dependancy. If it is added to android project then raised error as :

```
07-19 14:29:52.971 9123-9390/com.packaename.abc E/Unity: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.fabric.unity.android.FabricInitializer
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.fabric.unity.android.FabricInitializer
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:285)
    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c$1.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$c.run(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.fabric.unity.android.FabricInitializer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.packaename.abc-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.packaename.abc-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.packaename.abc-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLo
```

Is it possible manage android and unity different packages tracking crashlytics issues from same project and how to implement.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Are you trying to use both the Fabric Unity and Android implementation in the same app?

Comment: yes @MikeBonnell

Comment: Gotcha, we don't have a good way to support this currently. Something we want to address in the future. You would need to use one or the other implementation.

Comment: any other possibility for track crashlytics